# UIScrollView multiple page confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

So I have an existing app I'm working on for a friend...

[image]

and let's say I double click on animals_real and I get this screen...

[image]

Basically all I want to do is create a back button back to the home page on the animals_real page and all the other ones like it(body_parts_real, cleaning_real, etc.) but for whatever reason I can't find the xib file or the code for it and I'm not entirely sure what file it would be in. Also, since I am fairly new I'm not entirely sure how to implement the back button. Any help is greatly appreciated.

----------------------------------EDIT 1------------------------------------------

[image: Navigation]

The main page works under ViewControllerForIphone.xib and the settings page is under SettingViewControllerIphone.xib. This led me to believe that the other pages would be under the SubPECSViewController_iPhone.xib. However, if I go in and edit that it doesn't change anything when I run the simulator. So, basically I have been trying to understand UIScrollView better and how it works but I am kind of just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to iOS. Other commenters will point out that you should start here at the [UICollectionViewDelegate Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (which you can also get to through Xcode (shift+command+0)

Basically, a uicollection view populates itself based on some array of data.Look here to see what's going on

- (void)insertItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths

When you tap on animals, this method is called:

– collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

Some logic happens here, and I'm presuming you load the collectionview from yet another array.

To solve your original problem of a "back button," you might simply want to reload the viewcontroller's original datasource or possibly "pop" back up the navigation stack. Again, without seeing at least part of the code, there's very little we can do except speculate :)

Comment: Oh boy. I hate to say this, but you've got a couple days of pain ahead of you then. :) Storyboard is simply a way (and a great one) for quickly and visually organizing UI elements. In this case, you've got a scrollview that most likely houses a uicollection view. One of the classes .h/.m is should have the insertItemsAtIndexPath method I mentioned earlier... Look for that and you'll be closer to the answer. The "back" button isnt going to magically navigate to another XIB, rather, it looks like it'll have to call the original data array used to first populate the uicollection.